# Php payment solutions?

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating a php/mysql application for a university project and I am looking for any possible solution to allow users to buy from my site .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home_US) has a number of solutions for you, including services for Payflow Pro.

Answer (score 1):

[oscommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [Saferpay](http://www.saferpay.com) via command line utility. Will gladly follow this post for better options.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on writing the shopping cart as well?

We have been evaluating the Magento E-Commerce Platform, our initial tests show that it is pretty robust. It supports a bunch of payment gateway options.

Check it out... http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Answer (score 1):

An unofficial implementation in PHP: https://github.com/payment/saferpay

Protocol is described in https://www.six-payment-services.com/dam/saferpay/Saferpay_Payment_Page_EN.pdf, chapter 4.